# Table component with out main Query in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

How to display table component in *iReport* where we should not write a sql query in the main Query area?

Tried with empty data source but not found any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create a dataset first to be used for the table component.
When you drag and drop your table element, you can define your connection expression. by selecting, `'Use another connection'` and define your own connection.

Alternatively what I do is, just write a simple query in your main query area(master report) and establish a connection with your source . A simple query will be like

```
select '' as a
```

After you drag and drop your table component, in the connection part, click on 
`'Use the same connection used to fill the master report'` and continue with your report generation process which I feel is the easier way around.

Below is the image for your reference.
[image: Table Wizard]

Comment: First create a dataset to be used for the table and then drag and drop the table element onto your summary band. You will see the screen then.

Comment: Updated the answer for your reference